# How to make a smooth parallax effect with window scroll

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation, parallax

I am working on a website update project, in which I have to make a very simple parallax effect on one of the elements in one of the pages.

Result:
https://xchitox.github.io/test/parallax/example1.html

But the expected should be like this:
https://xchitox.github.io/test/parallax/example2.html

Because of the existing site and client's limitation, I can't add a wrapper `div` element to wrap all the content, and using additional 3rd party js library is not recommended. So how can I do it?

existing 3rd library available on the site:
jQuery, Foundation